# Why procedure if in C doesn't work with char

Tags: c, if-statement, char

I am writing a simple quiz in C (using CodeBlocks 13.12)

It compiles, but doesn't work in second question. Whatever I will input, it always give answer '*that's sad*'. 
I can't understand what is wrong. 
I came to this, where if I comment line 13 ( *scanf("%d", &age);* ) it's starting works ok for second question. 
What the problem is?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <clocale>


int main()
{

int age;
char S1;

printf("How old is your dog? \n");
scanf("%d", &age);

if (age <= 7)
    {
        printf(" very young. the end \n");
        return 0;
    }
else
    {
        printf("old dog. \n \n");
    }

//question2

printf("Do you like dogs? y/n \n");
scanf("%c%c", &S1);

if (S1 == 'y')
    {
         printf("hey, that's nice \n");
    }
else
    {
        printf(" that's sad :( . \n");
        return 0;
    }
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: why are you using 2x "%c" in your second scanf?

Comment: And why `<iostream>` and `<stdio.h>`? Don't mix C and C++. And why `<windows.h>`? Urgh.

Comment: Sorry sorry, I made a lot of changes and didn't notice to deleted it. My bad

Comment: This is not C. Remove the C++ headers.

Comment: Also, please indent your code if you expect others to read it. Use the edit button to fix indention and headers both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the second `scanf()` to

```
scanf(" %c", &S1);
```

This would escape the left out newline character `\n` in the input buffer.

Plus, you are reading one `char` in this. So you need only one `%c`

Comment: I deleted %c and it's compile. But when I run the program it ask first question, and when I answer over 7, it go to second question, automatically write answer 'that's sad' and end program.

Comment: @Andrew Notice the space before `%c`. Did you add that?

Comment: on my god, that's it! It will never occurred to me. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

You cause undefined behavior by

```
scanf("%c%c", &S1);
```

`scanf` reads **two** `char`s, one stored in `S1`, one stored in some location on the stack because `scanf` expects a **second** `char*` to be supplied.

If your intention is to ignore the newline following the actual character, write

```
scanf("%c%*c", &S1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
scanf("%c", &S1);
```

is the correct way to input one character ,

Comment: it should be a space before %c. Like this scanf(" %c", &S1);